# Simple way to convert integer to array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Does anybody have idea for easy clean way (maybe using ES6) to get

from "6" to array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` or "2" to `[1, 2]` etc.

I know I can use loop "for", but is there any shorter single-line way?

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried ?

Comment: btw, index starts with zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the spread operator on the created array  `[...Array(n).keys()]`

```js
console.log([...Array(6).keys()])
console.log([...Array(2).keys()])
// or
console.log(Array.from(Array(6).keys(), i => i+1));
console.log(Array.from(Array(2).keys(), i => i+1));
```

Comment: you can also apply a mapping function to get the same output as OP: `Array.from(Array(6).keys(), i => i+1)`

Comment: @NickParsons agreed

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with `mapFn`

```js
console.log(Array.from({length: 6}, (_, i) => i + 1));
console.log(Array.from({length: 2}, (_, i) => i + 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Array.from and it's callback

```js
let range = num =>  Array.from({ length: num }, (_, i) => ++i)

console.log(range(6))
console.log(range(2))
console.log(range(-6))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add the iterator, for example, to the prototype of `Number`, you could even spread numbers.

```js
Number.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this; i++) yield i;
};

console.log([...10]);
```